# Will the CSSStyleDeclaration returned through getComputedStyle always have the same length for a given browser?

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

I'm looking to compare two Elements to find all differences in their *computed styles*. In order to do this, I'm iterating over all styles of *A*, and comparing them to *B* by doing the following:

```
var stylesA = window.getComputedStyle(a),
    stylesB = window.getComputedStyle(b),
    length = stylesA.length,
    i, style;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    style = stylesA[i];
    if(stylesA[style] != stylesB[style]) {
        // Respond appropriately
    }
}
```

I'm doing this with the *assertion* that the length of A will *always be* the length of B, but I'm basing this purely through observation. Although the lengths are different from browser to browser (accounting for new properties, vendor prefixed versions etc.) the values are seemingly always the same:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll("*"),
    length = elms.length, i;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elms[i]).length);
}
```

Produces the following for all elements when applied to a random MDN page:

```
Chrome 35    253
Firefox 30   211
IE11         317
```

Now, clearly this isn't an exhaustive list of *all* browser, which makes me return to my question, *could these values be different for certain elements*? I found nothing looking at both the [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html) documents and the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) on `getComputedStyle()`.

In particular, I would have assumed that styles such as [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) and [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), which should only apply to certain Elements, would be in the list only when applicable. However both appears to be present regardless.

Is there a document somewhere which validates my assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion is indeed correct: there are no element-specific CSS styles as far as `getComputedStyle` is concerned. However, if you include elements from SVG or MathML (e.g. embedded using the `<svg>` tag) things might get more complicated.